# jquery remove everything after space

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to remove everything in my string after space like so:

```
value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].substring(0, value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].indexOf(' '))
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

What am I doing wrong ? This is inside an ajax call...here is the full ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/vendorProject/api/connection/getVendorItems?community=" + $("#communtiyDropdown").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (results) {
        var html;
        html = "<table border='1'>";
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<th>Task</th>";

        $.each(results, function (key, value) {
            html += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
        });

        html += "<th></th>";
        html += "</tr>";

        for (i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++) {
            html += "<tr>"
            html += "<td>" + taskArray[i] + "</td>";
            $.each(results, function (key, value) {
                html += "<td>" + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].substring(0, value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].indexOf(' '))  + "</td>";
            });

            html += "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkbox' /></td>"
            html += "</tr>";
       }

       html += "</table>";

       $("#tableData").html(html);
    }
});
```

The string in question is 12-12-2015 08:00:00 AM and I looking for 12-12-2015....no time.

Comment: It means that your code incorrectly assumes that `value.baseOrSchedStartList[i]` exists.

Comment: You're iterating over something called `taskArray` and somehow expect each `value` property in `result` to have the same length ?

Comment: value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] may be null or undefined, add a if condition, rest the code will work..

Comment: do a `console.log(value)` in `$.each(results, function (key, value) {`. Might give you some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to substr :)

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
    
      var a = $("input").val();
      
      var cropped = a;
      
      if(a.indexOf(" ")>=0) cropped = a.substr(0,a.indexOf(" "));
    
      $("b").html(cropped);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' placeholder='write something here and hit the button' style='width:60%;'>
<br>
<button>Ready!</button>
<br>
<div>
The result without space and after all : <b></b>
</div>
```